# Dificudade com array de dados vindo de varios campos input com name diferente

Tags: php, html

Descrição do Projeto:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="idComp[]" value="<?php echo $idComp?>"> </td>
<td><?php echo $nomeComp?></td>
<td><input type="text" value="1" name="qtdMax[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $valorV?>" readonly name="valorV[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="0" name="valorP[]"></td>
<?php 
$idComp = $_POST['idComp'];
        $qtdMax = $_POST['qtdMax'];
        $valorV = $_POST['valorV'];
        $valorP = $_POST['valorP'];
        
        foreach($idComp as $indice) {       
            print_r($indice);
        }
?>
```

estou com dificuldade no meu projeto
é uma lista de complemento, nessa lista o cliente seleciona qual complemento deseja, quando chega na minha classe nao consigo listar somente os dados selecionado

o id do complemento eu consigo pegar em um foreach e ver qual itens foram selecionado mas os campos qtdMax e valorP que sao dados inseridos pelo usuario nao vem de forma coreta

ja tentei de varias formas mas sempre vem de forma errada

Comment: Importante [editar sua postagem original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/581151/70) conforme instruido lá. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas continua funcional na primeira postagem.